# Scraping on Amazon Prime Now postcode entry

Tags: excel, vba, forms, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm looking to enter a postcode on primenow.amazon.co.uk submit the form and paste the results into excel

```
Sub PostCode_Delivery_Short()

Dim ie As Object
Dim form As Variant, button As Variant

'add the “Microsoft Internet Controls” reference in your VBA Project indirectly
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'Input box for postcode
    Postcode = InputBox("Enter Postcode")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ("primenow.amazon.co.uk")

'we ensure that the web page downloads completely before we fill the form automatically
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))

'assigning the vinput variables to the html elements of the form
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("availability__form__instructions__heading")(0).innertext = Postcode

'accessing the button via the form
Set form = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("form")

Set button = form(0).onsubmit
form(0).submit

End With

'cleaning up memory
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

What I'm struggling with is element ID (I think), I keep getting a runtime "error of Object variable or With block variable not set".

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByName` returns a collection, not a single element, so try something like:

```
ie.Document.getElementsByName("prime-now-input")(0).innertext = Postcode
```

**EDIT**  Also:

```
.Document.getElementsByTagName("availability__form__instructions__heading")
```

I'm pretty sure there's no HTML element with that tag name ;-)
Maybe you meant `getElementsByClassName()` ?

EDIT2: this is the element where you need to input the postcode (using .Value, not .innerText)

```
<input type="text" 
placeholder="Enter a postcode to see if we deliver to your area ..." 
maxlength="9" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.0.0.1.0.0">
```

My version of IE doesn't even render the input, so I can't offer more suggestions.

Comment: Nope, that didn't get it working, thanks for the help though.

Comment: Tried it again, with the class, but no luck... I've cut down the vba, have a look, if you don't mind

Comment: You will increase your chances of fixing this by 1) updating your question to show your current code and 2) indicating exactly which line(s) trigger the error.

Comment: Get as far as this line

    ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("availability__form__instructions__heading")(0).innertext = Postcode

Answer (score 0):

The website may have update and the below is for U.K. but it enters a postcode and presses the `Shop Now` (submit) button.

I use a CSS selector of `input[type='submit']` to target the submit button. It reads as element(s) with `input` tag having `type` attribute with value `'submit'`. The "[]" means attribute. Using the `querySelector` method to apply this selector will retrieve only the first match, as required.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SubmitPostCode()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Const URL As String = "https://primenow.amazon.co.uk/onboard?sourceUrl=%2F"
    Const POSTCODE As String = "WC1A 1DG"
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            .document.getElementById("lsPostalCode").Value = POSTCODE
            .document.querySelector("input[type='submit']").Click
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Stop '<== Delete me
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```